How would I make a flexible struct inside another struct?
I'm trying to create an item and box system, where a box can have a flexible amount of items inside it (i.e. not wasting memory by making every box have 50 items, when some will have just a few). I am not quite sure how to do it.
I tried to put the Item struct inside the Box struct as a flexible array, but it doesn't really work.
Here's my code:
struct Item {
    char name[64];
    char slot;
    int weight;
    int size;
    int dmg;
};

struct Box {
    int size;
    Item items[size];
};

int main()
{
    Item sword = { "Sword", 'W', 20, 8, 5};
    Box box = { 3, (sword, sword, sword) };
}


Why are you not using std::string and especially std::vector? std::vector<Item> seems to do exactly what you need.

Flexible array members are not standard C++. Which leaves you to figure out what your compiler requires of them and what it doesn't make possible.

I'm sorry, could you be more specific? I'm really new to using vectors and don't really know the difference between a string and char[].

@RobinBubeník C++ is complex, you cannot just pick it up as you go along. Find yourself a good book on C++, one that explains how to program effectively. There's really no other way to learn C++ (especially if it is your first language).

You can use dynamic allocation by using a pointer.struct Box {Item* item}; Box.item = new Item[3] Before using vector you must understand how pointers work.

@nikau6 it is worth mentioning that using a raw new requires a matching delete (or delete [] in this case) to avoid a memory leak.

A possible solution would be to use std::vector as a dynamic-size container.
You should also use std::string for strings like name (instead of a plain char array). Among other advatages, it will remove the limit of name length of 63 characters you have now.
A minimal example initializing a box with 3 items and then adding 1 item is demonstrated below:
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Item {
    std::string name;
    char slot;
    int weight;
    int size;
    int dmg;
};

struct Box {
    std::vector<Item> items;
};

int main()
{
    Item sword = { "Sword", 'W', 20, 8, 5 };
    Box box;
    box.items = { sword, sword, sword }; // initialize with 3 items
    box.items.push_back(sword);          // add another item
}

Notes:

Consider to encapsulate the data fields by making them private and providing accessor methods.
Consider to add constructors for Item and Box, and possibly other methods like add_item for Box.


I don't totally agree. I think when you're learning c++ you must understand first how char strings and pointers work before using std::string and std:vector. He's learning, he's not writing code in production.

@nikau6 I think there are different opinions regarding this issue. Some believe raw pointers etc. should actually be addressed after using the standard library common classes like string and vector. In any case I wanted to show the direction of a proper solution for this problem. You can post another answer demonstrating the usage of raw arrays for learning purposes.

@nikau6 • I think char strings and pointers (and new and delete) ought to be learned later, as an advanced C++ topic.

@Eljay This is not advanced C++ this are the bases on which C++ exists. You must learn the bases before the more abstract parts of the language. And it'll be much easier to deal with STL's container once you understand who they work.

@nikau6 • I disagree.  Those are advanced C++, not basics.  They are often taught as basics, because C++ is often taught as C.  With a progression that reflects the chronological order of functional going from C to C++ to C++98 to C++11 to C++14 to C++17 to C++20 to C++23.  Which is a disservice to students, because the parts of the language that were added later to make the language easier to learn are the last parts that are taught.

@Eljay Literally "bases" means being at the base. Pointer are the base, the foundation, of C++. Vectors are abstract types built on top of those foundations. Char strings are the foundations of std::string. Once you understand clearly the bases you know what's you're doing when using vector and string, and it's easier to learn. Today everybody teach you must learn advanced c++ before the bases because it's easier. I don't agree. And at the end you must know everything to pretend to be a c++ programmer.

@nikau6 assembly is even further down the foundation "hirarchy". But it doesn't mean you must (or even should) start with it when learning how to program.

@wohlstad Assembly is not part of the language, I don't know what you're taking about. They are no references to assembly in the official documentation.

@nikau6 I am aware it is not a part of the language. It was just an illustration regarding the foundations concept you mentioned. Because all the constructs in C++ eventually boil down to assembly and you could have argued one should understand it before climing up the abstraction ladder (and I would disagree). Anyway there could be different opinions in this matter and I think it's OK.

@wohlstad Yes but it's irrelevant regarding the subject we're concerned about.

@nikau6 IMHO it's relevant to the general subject of whether one must (or should) pass through all the levels in the abstraction ladder when learning a programming language. but I respect your right to disagree.

@wohlstad You can see more and more c++ programmer who don't understand pointers because they always use STL containers and STL's managed pointers (unique_ptr, shared_ptr) and this is a problem

Managing raw pointers should be done very rarely in my opinion. And in these rare cases it it should better be done by the more experinced C++ developers anyway. I am not saying it's bad to understand manual management of pointers. On the countrary. It good and can be useful. I'm just saying that it is an advanced issue that should be learned later.

@wohlstad Using raw pointer should be done rarely. But it doesn't mean that you don't have to understand very well how to use them. It's not "good" to understand pointers, this is essential.
